# How to link from parent source block to child block (included via <<noweb>>)?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, literate-programming

When exporting the documentation (HTML or PDF) for a literate program that uses noweb references in blocks, how can I get the output to actually hyperlink the `<<noweb_snippet_name>>` line (in the parent source code block) to the block named “`noweb_snippet_name`”?

Or, better yet, how can I make that noweb reference link to an arbitrary part of the exported document?  The child block might not be exported, so I would want the reference to link to the discussion of the snippet.

For example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC klingon-lisp :noweb tangle :exports code
...
<<declare_variables>>
<<conquer_worlds>>
<<declare_victory>>
...
#+END_SRC

...
... /much later in the org file/
* Global variables
Blah blah discussion of variables, blah blah...
| Variable name | Description |

#+NAME: declare_variables
#+BEGIN_SRC klingon-lisp :exports none
(defvar yuQ nil
  "yuQmey chargh tetlh.")
#+END_SRC
```

Here, the main program source block is exported, to document the structure of the program.  The subsidiary block `declare_variables` does not need to be included in the export, since the text describes the variables and lists them in a table.  Ideally, `<<declare_variables>>` in the exported main program block would link to the `* Global variables` header.  But I could live with it linking to the `declare_variables` source block, and having to export that as well.